# Flowbite datepicker z-index issue in modal

Tags: html, css, datepicker, flowbite, daisyui

I have the following simple setup:

```html
<!-- Setup -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.7.3/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/datepicker.min.js"></script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="h-screen w-screen grid place-content-center bg-indigo-600">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="modal.showModal()">open modal</button>
</div>
<dialog id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-box">
    
      <!-- Datepicker -->
      <input datepicker datepicker-autohide type="text" class="border rounded z-50 w-full" placeholder="Select date" style="z-index: 10000!important">
    
  </div>
  <form method="dialog" class="modal-backdrop">
    <button>close</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

The issue is, that the datepicker is behind the backdrop and whatever I try with z-index and relative positions, it always stays behind the backdrop.

Comment: The problem is that the datepicker dropdown element gets added as the last child of `body`, outside of the `dialog` element. Not sure if there's anything that can be done about this, if you want to keep the "native" backdrop functionality.

Comment: Even if I add an infinite high z-index to it in the browser dev tools after it gets displayed, it stays behind the backdrop

Comment: That's not surprising, z-index is more complex than just "the highest number _always_ wins." And the _point_ of such a backdrop is that nothing "outside" is supposed to be above it to begin with.

Comment: So the solution is, to not use a native backdrop, but fake it?

Comment: Or try and find a datepicker library that lets you specify, _where_ the dropdown should be inserted into the DOM. If you managed to get it _into_ the dialog, then it might work better.